# Vue's @click function doesn't work in Firefox but works in Edge,Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
const main = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        result: "",
        responseAvailable: false,
        currentOpen: null
    },
    methods: {

        fetchData: function(event) {
            
            this.responseAvailable = false;

            fetch("https://restapihost.net/cms", {
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic cmsdfkKKMNijiweeuiVzdGFwaTpyZXN0YXBp'
                }
            })
            .then(response => { 
                if(response.ok){
                    return response.json()    
                } else{
                    alert("Server returned " + response.status + " : " + response.statusText);
                }                
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.result = response.data; 
                this.responseAvailable = true;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            }); 
        }

    }
});
```

```css
button {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.content {
  
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show { 
display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Responsive + Encoding Meta Tag -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link href = "styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>API Call</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>API Call Example</h1>
        <button @click="fetchData">Get Index</button>
        <div v-if="responseAvailable == true" >
            <div name="list">
                <div v-for="i in result" class="elem">
                        <p :data-id="i.id" @click="currentOpen=i.id"><i>{{i.title}} </i></p>
                       <div v-bind:class="{'hide':true, 'show':(i.id === currentOpen)}" v-bind:id="i.id" v-html="i.content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- Vue and Custom JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<script src = "scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

The @click function on the button (get Index) does'nt work in Firefox. I have tried other Browsers like Chrome etc.. They all works fine.
Firefox does nothing.
I've tested @click="fetchData", @click="fetchData(event)", @click.native="fetchData" Nothing works.

Can anyone explain what's wrong with my POS?

Comment: I'm on firefox, the example works fine

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that you shouldn't be querying the DOM when you're using vue; should be using vue data

Comment: @DerekPollard
you mean the toogleElement function, or?

Comment: Yes, that's the method I'm referencing

Comment: You have to provide a [mcve] which actually repros the issue on Firefox. What you have posted here does not. As a wild guess it might be a CSS related issue where, because of some weird CSS rules, on FF only, your button is overlapped by some other element so you're not actually clicking on it. Without a way to repro, we can't help. Also, you haven't mentioned your FF version, nor your OS or device.

Comment: Or maybe the click is working but FF blocks your request. Console is your friend.

Comment: Typically with Vue your button press would just change some piece of the data model and your elements would show or not based on that data, probably using `v-if` or maybe `v-show`, such as `<div v-if="scheduled && startTime > 1800">overtime block</div>`, like your `v-if="responseAvailable == true"` (side-note: you seldom have to compare `== true`, just say `v-if="responseAvailable"` unless there's a chance it could be _truthy_ but not `true`)

Answer (score 0):

Problem found.
The Code is ok and has no Problems.
Firefox has terminated the JS-Engine. Reason is unknown to me.